# Requete ajax to a php file that returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I saw that I was not the only one with such a problem, but I did not find a solution.

So the problem comes from an application much more complex than that, but trying to target the problem I realized that even a simple "Ajax" request between 2 or 3 files returns me "undefined".

Here are my files :

index.php

```
<body>
  <button>Button</button>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('button').click(function(){
    $.post('test.php', function(data, status){
      console.log('data: ' + data, status);
    });
  });
});
```

test.php

```
<?php
  echo "lorem ipsum";
?>
```

When I click on the button the Ajax request returns that in there console:

```
data: undefined success
```

---

When my file is an index.php file it always returns "undefined" no matter the context (Of course if there is no Javascript error).
But by doing several tests I realized different results with the same content but with other file extensions, the returns are not always the same, for example:

index.html instead of index.php, same main.js and same test.php

```
data:  success
```

index.html instead of index.php, and if I call a test.txt file that contains for example "lorem ipsum" it returns this :

```
data: lorem ipsum success
```

That's my problem, thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: strange, in your code there is no error, are you in local server or in a web server?can be some problem of configuration for example htaccess?strange....i suppose the link of the php it's ok the file url it's correct...it seems a problem of access to determinates extension files...

Comment: its working fine for me. can you post your full code?

Comment: Oh I hadn't seen your answers, so I'm on my local server hosted on a VM "ubuntu server" and here's the only part of the code I haven't already shown you:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Ajax - Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <button>Button</button>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="./main.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
Sorry about the code display, I don't know how else to do it. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it came from my work environment, I used this plugin https://github.com/JosephLenton/PHP-Error and by disabling it everything was working correctly ^^'

Now I have to figure out how to keep it activated while making Ajax requests xD

Thank you all for your help and sorry for wasting your time. :/

Answer (score 0):

well, i think you have to send json instead of echo like this:

```
return json_encode('lorem ipsum');
```

try this i hope it help.

Comment: I tried it anyway and it still doesn't work, even with echo or print_r() and json_encode(). Thank you :)

Comment: To tell you the truth, I try to copy and paste some tutorials to see if they worked, and they didn't work either. ^^'

Comment: open console of your browser and go to tab network and click button then there will appear a request you can see there full error

Comment: I don't see any mistakes. ^^'

Comment: Convert your request type to get instead of post

Comment: Same result with get :)

Comment: Do you try to log your data alone?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your test.php file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<button>Button</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('button').click(function(){
    $.post('abc.php', function(data, status){
      console.log('data: ' + data, status);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

in your abc.php file just put this and check and put test.php and abc.php in same folder or if abc.php is in another location just change the url of abc.php in $.post

```
<?php echo "hello"; ?>
```

Comment: The result in the console is: data: undefined success ^^'

Comment: that's not possible i have checked this code and its working fine, can you check your network for any errors and send me a screenshot .

Comment: Check preview and response tab of network and also check if any errors in network when hitting request

Comment: In the preview there are empty, in the response there are "This request has no response data available." and i don't know where to look for check if there are error in the network window, but I didn't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

here try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.php",
      success: function(result) {
        $("#div").html(result);
      } 
    });
  });
});
```

Then for the php code:

```
$array = array("" => "lorem", "" => " ipsum");
echo json_encoded($array);
```